# Map clashing with WP - suggestions on fix?

Tags: html5, map

I've followed this tutorial - http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/ to create a state map of USA which you can see here - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/neurosign/contact/alabama/

I downloaded the source files and got it all working locally then uploaded all the files to the link above. It's almost working but the hover doesn't seem to work when you hover over each state. I had this working locally but cannot work out why it's not working online.

One cause may be that Wordpress (that's what the site is built on) is blocking something along the way.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
It's blatantly something clashing with Wordpress as it worked locally, does anyone have any idea's of how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using FireBug for FireFox or the Google Chrome Developer Tools (both available on Win via [F12]-key), then you can see that you're missing ressources (404) via your Console Tab in the tool bar:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

The list of "missing" files:

- tooltip.css
- mapper.js
- wz_jsgraphics.js
- cvi_tip_lib.js
- maputil.js

When looking at your source than I'd say, your pathes are simply wrong.

Try to use `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );` for javascript file pathes and `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );` for stylesheets.

Comment: Or just [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) to build URLs to files themselves.

Comment: @Rarst This shouldn't be a comment, but rather an edit of my Q.

Comment: @Rarst Get some rep, make your edit :)